# R: if a value is less or is na update another data.frame

Tags: r

I have two data.frames `A` and `B`.

`A` contains negative, absolute and NA values.

`B` contains only positive and NA values.

The dimensions of the data frames are the same.

data.frame `A` looks like this:

```
ENSMUSG00000000001.4/Gnai3   0.1943315     0.3021675             NA             NA  
ENSMUSG00000000003.9/Pbsn   -1.4843914    -1.2608270     -0.2587953    -0.46167430
ENSMUSG00000000028.8/Cdc45  -0.2388901    -0.1106236      0.9046436     0.08968331
ENSMUSG00000000037.9/Scml    0.3242902     0.5385371      0.2311202     0.51110287
ENSMUSG00000000049.5/Apoh   -1.7606033    -1.8159545     -0.2087083    -1.09614630
ENSMUSG00000000056.7/Narf    NA            NA            -0.3747798    -0.55547798
```

I need to check if a value is NA or negative in this table then I need to update data.frame `B` on the same indices to the value `0.999`.

For example:
The first record of `A` has two `NA` values, indexes are [1,4] and [1,5] meaning, I will update `B[1,4]=0.999` and `B[1,5]=0.999`.

I could do this in the nested loops for columns and rows but it would take too much time. Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a Boolean mask as an index if it's the same size:

```
b[is.na(a) | a < 0] <- 0.999
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `ifelse` to do this, since the dataframes have the same dimensions.

```
A<-matrix(data=1:15,nrow=5) # create matrices (works with dataframe as well)
B<-matrix(data=16:30,nrow=5)

B[1,2]<-NA # introduce some NA and negative values
B[5,3]<-(-1)

ifelse(is.na(B) | B<=0,A,B) # new matrix with "updated" values
```

Comment: As the question is written, you'd need `ifelse(is.na(B) | B < 0, A, 0.999)`